# Make sure this refers to the object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
dog = {
  location: {
    x: 52.1089,
    y: 16.2323
  },
  f: function(message) {
    alert(message + this.location.x);
    return;
  }
};
```

Now I need to start passing the function `dog.f` to an API in different contexts. My problem is that `this` not always refers to my object but to different things depending on how it is called. How can I access properties like `location` inside the function `f`?

EDIT: What I actually want is only the method `f`but I dont want to initialize location inside `f` on each function call, so I thought an object would be the best idea. This was my first attempt:

```
var f = function(message) {
    var location: {
      x: 52.1089,
      y: 16.2323
    }
    alert(message + location.x);
    return;
  }
```

but it looks wasteful to initialiaze location on every function call.

EDIT 2: I am open for a coffeescript solution

Comment: I'd suggest spinning through some JS OOP tutorials; it looks like you want to emulate a class.

Comment: Yes, please see my edit. I want a function with state but I thought a class would be overkill and an object would do.

Comment: CoffeeScript has baked-in classes, I don't get the objection to using one.

Comment: The only issue I have with it is the need to initialize it before you get an instance. I was hoping I could directly create an object. In the end I went for a closure, clean enough in Coffeescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using a closure (see [*Private Members in JavaScript*](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)):

```
var dog = (function() {
  var location = {x: 52, y:16};
  return {
    getLocation: function() {
      return [location.x, location.y];
    },
    setLocation: function (newX, newY) {
      location.x = newX;
      location.y = newY;
    },
    showMessage: function(message) {
      alert(message + location.x);
    }
  };
}());

dog.showMessage('here : ');
```

Comment: This is in principle what I want, a closure. I was hoping that an object would do it as the code looks cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context for the method:

```
var func = dog.f.bind(dog);
```

When you call `func` from anywhere, it will have the same context as if it was called as `dog.f`.

Note: The `bind` method isn't supported in older browsers, for example IE 8 and older, so you would need a 'polyfill' if you need to support those. There is one in the documentation that I linked to.

Comment: where should that line go, outside of the object?

Comment: Can I "autobind" my f function inside the object?

Comment: @Elian: You use that wherever you want a reference to the method with the object bound to it. You actually only need the expression on the right side, I put it in an assignment to show how you can use it. You can't autobind it in the object, as the object doesn't exist yet when the function is created.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this

```
var Dog = function() {
  this.location = {
    x: 52.1089,
    y: 16.2323
  };
  this.f = function(message) {
    alert(message + this.location.x);
    return;
  }
};

var dogObj = new Dog();

dogObj.f("Hellow World!");
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the instance creation `var dogObj = new Dog();` but it might well be the case that I will have to do that.

Comment: That won't solve the problem. When you pass the value of `dogObj.f` somewhere and it's called, `this` will still not be the object.